# STM32F4 rx data loss when transmitting

Tags: c, stm32, uart

Application is simple.
When uart receiving is completed, transmit received data.
But the problem is during transmitting data, receive data is ignored like picture below.
packet 1 is about 26K bytes. It takes about 237.
And other packets are about 2K bytes.

Packets 2~4 are ignored:
[image: image showing packets where packets 2 ~ 4 are ignored]

I tried uart dma, interrupt. but still data is ignored.
Is there any other way?

MCU : STM32F413
baudrate : 921600 bps

Comment: I'm sure there is a way. Do you know why it *doesn't* receive during the transmit? Show the relevant parts of your code

Comment: If you use uart by interrupt or dma it should just work. You have bugs and/or logic errors in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use any DMA or IRQ Handles?

I would prefer to use DMA in parallel RX/TX application. It is a good approach to offload the CPU with HW tasks. The DMA is very powerful in the STM32.

Switch to

`HAL_UART_Receive_DMA()` and `HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA()` most of the work is there already done.